# Using a function within ddply

Tags: r, if-statement, plyr

I'm having an issue writing functions into a ddply call. Here is a basic DF:

```
library(plyr)

Time <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
X <- c(1,2,-3,4,-7,2,-4,9,7,-5)
Y <- c(2,-3,-4,4,4,3,2,-9,9,10)
T <- c(5,4,3,2,1,9,8,7,6,5)
DF <- data.frame(Time,X,Y,T)
```

I have two different functions. One that looks to subtract a number from T depending on the results of a two column statement

```
VD<-function(X,Y,T){
    if(X > 0 & Y < 0) {9-T}
    if(X < 0 & Y < 0) {5-T}
    if(X > 0 & Y > 0) {9-T}
    if(X < 0 & Y > 0) {5-T}
}
```

and a second that just looks at whether a number is negative or positive (subtract x from 9 if negative number, do nothing if positive number)

```
VD2<-function(X){
    if(X<0) {9-X}
    if(X>0) {X}
}
```

I wrote what I thought would work

```
ddply(DF,'Time',summarize,Result=VD(X,Y,T))

ddply(DF,'Time',summarize,Result2=VD2(X))
```

But I get errors for both, and I'm not sure why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to return the result in the function i.e.

```
VD<-function(X,Y,T){
if(X > 0 & Y < 0) {return(9-T)}
if(X < 0 & Y < 0) {return(5-T)}
if(X > 0 & Y > 0) {return(9-T)}
if(X < 0 & Y > 0) {return(5-T)}
}
```

Comment: Also, the function `VD2` doesn't return anything when `X>0` so it will give an error when trying to use it in `ddply`.

Answer (score 2):

```
VD<-function(X,Y,T){
if(X > 0 & Y < 0) {k=9-T}
if(X < 0 & Y < 0) {k=5-T}
if(X > 0 & Y > 0) {k=9-T}
if(X < 0 & Y > 0) {k=5-T}
return(k)
}
library(plyr)
 ddply(DF,'Time',summarize,Result=VD(X,Y,T))
   Time Result
1     1      4
2     2      5
3     3      2
4     4      7
5     5      4
6     6      0
7     7     -3
8     8      2
9     9      3
10   10      0

VD2<-function(X){
    if(X<0) {k=9-X}
     if(X>0) {k=X}
     return(k)
 }
> ddply(DF,'Time',summarize,Result2=VD2(X))
   Time Result2
1     1       1
2     2       2
3     3      12
4     4       4
5     5      16
6     6       2
7     7      13
8     8       9
9     9       7
10   10      14
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibilities that also work, in "one" function:

```
  data2 <- plyr::ddply (DF, "Time", .fun=function(xx){
    c(Result=ifelse(xx[,"X"] > 0 & xx[,"Y"] < 0, {k=9-xx[,"T"]},
             ifelse(xx[,"X"] < 0 & xx[,"Y"] < 0, {k=5-xx[,"T"]}, 
             ifelse(xx[,"X"] > 0 & xx[,"Y"] > 0, {k=9-xx[,"T"]},
             ifelse(xx[,"X"] < 0 & xx[,"Y"] > 0, {k=5-xx[,"T"]}))))
    )})
#or

  data3 <- plyr::ddply (DF, "Time", .fun=function(xx){
    c(Result=     if(xx[,"X"] > 0 & xx[,"Y"] < 0) {k=9-xx[,"T"]}
             else if(xx[,"X"] < 0 & xx[,"Y"] < 0) {k=5-xx[,"T"]} 
             else if(xx[,"X"] > 0 & xx[,"Y"] > 0) {k=9-xx[,"T"]}
             else if(xx[,"X"] < 0 & xx[,"Y"] > 0) {k=5-xx[,"T"]}
  )})

# or 

data4 <- plyr::ddply (DF, "Time", .fun=function(df,t="T"){
  c(Result=ifelse(with(df, X > 0 & Y < 0), {k=9-df[,t]},
           ifelse(with(df, X < 0 & Y < 0), {k=5-df[,t]}, 
           ifelse(with(df, X > 0 & Y > 0), {k=9-df[,t]},
           ifelse(with(df, X < 0 & Y > 0), {k=5-df[,t]}))) )
  )})
data4
#or

data5 <- plyr::ddply (DF, "Time", .fun=function(df,t="T"){
  c(Result= if(with(df, X > 0 & Y < 0)) {k=9-df[,t]}
    else if(with(df, X < 0 & Y < 0)) {k=5-df[,t]} 
    else if(with(df, X > 0 & Y > 0)) {k=9-df[,t]}
    else if(with(df, X < 0 & Y > 0)) {k=5-df[,t]}
  )})
data5
```